# JKS protection

Tags: java, security, encryption, jks

Are JKS (Java Key Store) files encrypted? Do they provide full protection for encryption keys, or do I need to rely solely on access control?
Is there a way to ensure that the keys are protected?

I'm interested in the gritty details, including algorithm, key management, etc. Is any of this configurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are encrypted.

The algorithm is provider dependent. The provider will return the key/certificate based on a password. If you need strong security, find a keystore provider that uses a strong encryption.

Comment: Thanks, can I have more details? Algorithm, key management, etc

Comment: I think it is dependent on the KeyStore provider. 

You can take a look at this link if it helps (http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=170967&seqNum=2)

Comment: Yeah, those links (especially the second) helped. So in short, its *kinda* encrypted, just not particularly well.

Answer (score 6):

To be more precise:

- PrivateKeys and SecretKeys within a
  JKS file are encrypted with their own password.
- Integrity of trusted certificates is protected with a MAC using the key store password.
- The file as a whole is not
  encrypted, and an attacker can list
  its entries without the key store
  password.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on the details? Algorithms, key management, how do i configure this all?