# applet signing - lost keystore password

Tags: java, jar-signing, code-signing-certificate, signed-applet, verisign

I have a question regarding the steps I should follow to use an old keystore (for which I've lost the password).

Is there any way to use the certificate I received from Verisign if I can't import that certificate into the original keystore (because I don't remember the password)?

--

The steps that led me here were:

1. I ran:

   > ```
   > keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -keystore jarkeys -alias thekey -keysize 2048
   > ```
2. Keytool requested the password, I entered at that time a password.
3. I filled in the organizational info, then I got the CSR and sent to Verisign.
4. Now I received the certificate, but I don't know how to use it since I can't add it to the Keystore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing the certificate issued by Verisign back into the keystore is pointless. What you need is access to the private key, generated during the `-genkey` process.

One of the main purposes of the key password is to protect access to the private key, by [encrypting the private (or secret) keys with it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/176188/372643). You shouldn't be able to get the private key back without this password.

What you may be able to do is to re-generate a new CSR and ask Verisign to re-issue a certificate. Some CAs do this for free during the certificate validity period.

Comment: Thanks. I've been able to export "the key" mentioned above with the export (keytool -export -alias thekey -file mydomain.crt -keystore jarkeys) command without any password. Could it mean that the keystore didn't had a password? Does this helps in any way?

Comment: You only export the certificate with `-export`, not the private key. You'll certainly have to create a new key-pair and CSR and re-apply.