What is the purpose of the bcfks format
I have a .jks file that's being used for the keystore to launch an application through tomcat 9.
I believe the .jks file isn't FIPS compliant because some of the algorithms being used are SHA1. Which from what I understand, isn't FIPS compliant. My question is, does converting a file from .jks to a .bcfks file automatically make it FIPS compliant or are there other factors besides the file format?
I'm sorry if this is a very basic question but I'm new to FIPS and I've struggled to find a clear explanation on what exactly makes something FIPS compliant.
I'm attempting to convert a .jks format keystore file into a bcfks format using the bcprov-jdk-1.64.jar file and the following keytool command:
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore trust.jks -srcstoretype JKS -srcstorepass -destkeystore trust.bcfks -deststorepass -deststoretype BCFKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath ./BouncyCastle/bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar

Just because you are using JKS, it doesn't mean you are also using SHA1. Also, it's possible to enable/disable crypto algorithms in Java and I think this also applies to hashing algorithms.

@dan1st I think the OP meant "MD5" - JCEKS uses DESEde/CBC/Pkcs5 to encrypt the keys, but it also uses MD5 for key derivation. BKS uses SHA1 for key derivation, hence the possible confusion.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597469/encryption-used-by-jceks-keystore-in-javatm-cryptography-extension

In order for a solution to be FIPS compliant, every aspect of the solution needs to be FIPS compliant, the OS, the keystores, the cryptographic processes, the procedures etc. That said - "FIPS compliant" is something that you claim that no one actually comes and checks. "FIPS certified" or "FIPS validated" is a different story. FIPS is a comprehensive set of standards so it is impossible to write what it means in a SO answer.
