# How application server is reading custom trust store without password

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, jboss-eap-6, truststore

I have created custom truststore using keytool and provided password while creating it. I configured  Jboss EAP to use the trust store using the following options:

> JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore.jks"

I didn't provide any truststore password in jboss configuration.

My question is how jboss is able to read the trust store without password ?
I am seeing that the outbound ssl connections from servers are working fine after configuring the trust store.

Comment: does your truststore has even a password?
or is it the default "changeit"?

Comment: it has password

Answer (score 1):

The password is not really needed to read the truststore entries of a JKS. The file is not encrypted and only the private keys are encrypted with their own password. See [JKS protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174131/jks-protection) See also this [example code](https://gist.github.com/zach-klippenstein/4631307) to change JKS password without know the orginal

It seems that the cryptographic provider used by your Jboss deployment is omitting the password to read the entries